# Issuer certificate issue for Prisma generate command

Tags: ssl, certificate, prisma

Whenever I am trying to run "prisma generate" I am getting error :
Request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/0362da...... failed,reason  : unable to get local issuer certificate

I already tried setting strictSSL to false.

I am working in a corporate network. Is there any solution in that respect?

Comment: Does your company require you to use a proxy?

Comment: Not sure. For other Node installation we don't need any proxy setup. Company do use zscaler for security purposes.

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2660#issuecomment-1096866912?

Comment: @NurulSundarani that only works for Windows.

Comment: Which OS are you using?